# How to Add Plug-ins to Rational Functional Tester (RFT) (eg. add Apache HttpCore) or Clone RFT Environment?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rft

There is one installation of RFT in Machine_1, I have installed the IBM Rational Functional Tester  (RFT) in Machine_2, I see that in "Help>About Rational Functional Tester>Plug-in Details" Plug-in Details table some Plug-ins are missing from Machine_2 when I compare with the same plug-in table in the Machine_1.

1. Do I need to install the missing Plug-ins to have the same RFT environment in Machine_1 and Machine_2 or is there any way to transfer all the environment settings (Plug-ins etc.) of Machine_1 to Machine_2?
2. How can I add the "Apache HttpCore" Plug-in that is missing from Plug-in Details table to Machine_2?

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue you have on machine_1 ? That Apache Http plugin I think is not really used by RFT .. may be its just part of Eclipse Shell used by RFT. What is the version of RFT that you use  in  Machine_1 and Machine_2. Do you need to use some APIs  from  Apache HttpCore?